# env: bash\r: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, git, bash, line-endings, core.autocrlf

I'm trying to install YouCompleteMe from [here](http://christopherpoole.github.io/setting-up-vim-with-YouCompleteMe/).

When I execute:

```sh
./install.sh --clang-completer
```

I get this error:

```sh
env: bash\r: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what's wrong with environment variables. Here's my bash path:

```sh
which bash 
/bin/bash
```

Do I need to change it to `/usr/bash`? If yes, then how should I do that? I tried changing `~/.bashrc` file, but it didn't work.

Comment: If your error was an error, it would probably contain the word "error". It is good that the "bash\r" file was not found because file names can't contain "\".

Comment: A quick fix :) just edit your script in notepad ++ editor and change the EOL conversion to UNIX(LF). I have also faced same issue after changing the EOL conversion to UNIX(LF) it is start working.

Comment: WSL on Windows? See: [After installing npm on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 I get the message "/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938486/after-installing-npm-on-wsl-ubuntu-20-04-i-get-the-message-usr-bin-env-bash/67938487#67938487)

Answer (score 307, accepted):

The error message suggests that **the script you're invoking has embedded `\r` characters**, which in turn suggests that it has **Windows-style `\r\n` line endings** (newlines) instead of the `\n`-only line endings `bash` expects.

As a **quick fix**, you can remove the `\r` chars. as follows:

```
sed $'s/\r$//' ./install.sh > ./install.Unix.sh
```

<sup>Note: The `$'...'` string is an [ANSI-C quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) supported in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`. It is used to ensure that the `\r` expands to an actual CR character before `sed` sees the script, because not all `sed` implementations themselves support `\r` as an escape sequence.</sup>

and then run

```
./install.Unix.sh --clang-completer
```

However, the larger question is why you've ended up with `\r\n`-style files - most likely, other files are affected, too.

Perhaps you're running **Git on Windows**, where a **typical configuration is to convert Unix-style `\n`-only line breaks to Windows-style `\r\n` line breaks on *checking files out* and re-converting to `\n`-only line breaks on *committing***.

While this ***somewhat* makes sense for *development***<sup>[1]</sup> on Windows, it **gets in the way of *installation* scenarios** like these.

To **make Git check out files with Unix-style file endings on Windows** - at least temporarily - use:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then run your installation commands involving `git clone` again.

To restore Git's behavior later, run `git config --global core.autocrlf true`.

---

<sup>[1] These days, most editors and CLIs on Windows can handle `\r\n` and `\n` newlines *interchangeably*.</sup>

Comment: Had a similar issue with `sbt` installed through sdkman. For such cases, it's useful to first locate the problematic script with `whereis sbt`, then apply above command.

Comment: sed: can't read ./install.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Quiet strange I got the same error, but my line endings are fine. I checked it with `xxd`. This is related to WSL and [the solution is in another comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045140/env-bash-r-no-such-file-or-directory#comment123727790_29045140)

Answer (score 57):

It is happening due to windows line endings. To fix the issue follow below steps

For MAC:

```
brew install dos2unix # Installs dos2unix Mac
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \; # recursively removes windows related stuff
```

For Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install -y dos2unix # Installs dos2unix Linux
sudo find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \; # recursively removes windows related stuff
```

And make sure your git config is set as follows:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

`input` makes sure to convert CRLF to LF when writing to the object database

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had an issue when running a RN project. react-native run-android wasn't working. Tried all the possible scenarios to fix the issue. Finally this helps to fix that.

Comment: @salvi I followed above steps in my project folder after deleting node modules but in vscode terminal it works fine but not in WSL2 terminal why so?

Comment: This doesn't work for mac, I still get the same message

Comment: @ElKePoN make sure your git config is set as per the last step

Comment: Actually it should be true, not input. What is input used for? This is how it should be `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Comment: @ElKePoN git config --global core.autocrlf true is recommended for windows as we need to replace CRLF with LF when writing to the object database and then again convert LF to CRLF when writing out into the working directory to retain CRLF on our local.But, if you follow the same for MAC you will be left with CRLF in your working directory. That's why input is used, to only convert CRLF to LF when writing to object database and do NOT do the reverse.

Answer (score 52):

```
>vim gradlew
:set fileformat=unix
:wq
>./gradlew clean build
```

Answer (score 37):

If you are using VS Code, you can switch from `CRLF` to `LF` and save the file again. This will replace all CRLF with LF.

[image]

Comment: This works even in Windows 

Comment: Tested on Windows and confirmed it worked. Just restart the container in Docker after saving the file and it should work.

Answer (score 24):

Quick command for converting line ending:

```
dos2unix thescript.sh
```

Answer (score 20):

Your file has Windows line endings. Change to Unix line endings.

Answer (score 16):

Ran into something similar. You can use `dos2unix install.sh` to convert the line endings. Multiple files via `find [pattern] | xargs dos2unix`

Comment: You could use: `find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;`

Answer (score 11):

In my case I had a wrong git configuration. The git documentation states:

> If you’re programming on Windows and working with people who are not
>   (or vice-versa), you’ll probably run into line-ending issues at some
>   point

I'm using Mac OS and I exactly have this issue in one of my projects. To solve it I turned `autocrlf` to `true` which was wrong.

You can check the `autocrlf` state of your git configuration like this:

```
git config core.autocrlf
```

So if this returns `true` and the problem occurs within a git repository you'll have to change that configuration to

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

on a Mac / Unix system. For Windows only projects you can use

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

In my case I deleted the git repository and cloned it again and after that everything worked again as expected.

Find out more at https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 2):

I used to have this problem when I tried to downgrade flutter

this solved my issue

```
rm -rf flutter
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git clone git@github.com:flutter/flutter.git
flutter channel stable
```

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me solving the issue.
https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker/issues/127

I edited my .sh file, replacing all CRLF with LF

Comment: That's a very terrible thing to do. Please refer to the numerous better solutions provided above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
This error occurs when I downloaded and unzip the WINDOWS version into MAC

and then added the windows version path to .bash_profile or .zprofile

so the solution for me was to remove the paths from (.bash_profile and .zprofile)
then download the mac version by opening the terminal and type:

1. mkdir src
2. cd src
3. git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
4. export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
5. flutter doctor