# zsh: permission denied: bin/rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, zsh, iterm, oh-my-zsh

I have recently bought a new Macbook and have installed Rails, Ruby, Git, Homebrew, and Postgres successfully. I can open my app in atom but when I try to run a migration or drop the database, ZSH gives me a permission denied error. Is there something I'm missing / have forgotten to install?

`➜ SYT git:(master) ✗ bin/rake db:migrate
zsh: permission denied: bin/rake
➜  SYT git:(master) ✗ bin/rake db:drop
zsh: permission denied: bin/rake`

Comment: what's the output of `ls -la bin`?

Comment: My computer's name is Bonaparte:

`➜  SYT git:(master) ✗ ls -la bin`
`total 48`
`drwxr-xr-x@  8 Bonaparte  staff  272 20 Jul 17:25 .`
`drwxr-xr-x@ 22 Bonaparte  staff  748 21 Jul 18:02 ..`
`-rw-rw-rw-@  1 Bonaparte  staff  129 15 Jun  2014 bundle`
`-rw-rw-rw-@  1 Bonaparte  staff  219 10 Mar 14:59 rails`
`-rw-rw-rw-@  1 Bonaparte  staff  164 15 Jun  2014 rake`
`-rw-rw-rw-@  1 Bonaparte  staff  372  8 Jul 18:12 rspec`
`-rw-rw-rw-@  1 Bonaparte  staff  805 10 Mar 14:59 setup`
`-rw-rw-rw-@  1 Bonaparte  staff  461 10 Mar 14:59 spring`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Apparently the contents of `bin` directory do not have permission to be executed. You can fix it with

```
chmod +x bin/*
```

Comment: This worked, have moved on to a new error now ;) thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixed it, but cause another error and found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70422769/11878732