# ./gradlew No such file or directory - Android studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-2.2

When i try to build the android app from command line in the android studio . I get command not found. but im able to run the app with the play button.

```
 M01GMBS30ZVG8WP:paylahmerchant dheerajprasad$ ls
MobileSDK          gradle                  merchant.iml
MPChartLib              gradle.properties       popuplibrary
app                     gradlew                 settings.gradle
build                   gradlew.bat             webapilibrary
build.gradle            local.properties

M01GMBS30ZVG8WP:paylahmerchant dheerajprasad$ ./gradlew assemble
env: bash\r: No such file or directory
```

But when i run the same command for the different project , gradle command works as expected.

Please help on this.

Comment: Make it executable: sudo chmod +x gradlew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was all the commands was converted to windows commands.

running this command replaced the content to correct format.

sed $'s/\r$//' ./source > ./destination

[env: bash\r: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045140/env-bash-r-no-such-file-or-directory)