# Docker compose containers fail and exit with code 127 missing /bin/env bash

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker so bear with me for any wrong term.

I have Docker Tools installed on Windows 7 and I'm trying to run a Docker compose file of a proprietary existing project stored in a git repository and that has probably been only run on Linux.

These are the commands I ran:

1. `docker-machine start`
2. `docker-machine env`
3. `@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env') DO @%i`

   - this was output by step (2)
4. `docker-compose -f <docker-file.yml> up`

Most of the Docker work has gone fine (image download, extraction, etc).

It is failing at container start, where some containers run fine - I recognize a working MongoDB instance since its log doesn't report any error - but other containers exit pretty soon with an error code, i.e.:

```
frontend_1 exited with code 127
```

Scrolling up a bit the console, I can see lines like:

```
No such file or directoryr/bin/env: bash
```

I have no idea where to go from here. I tried launching composer from a CygWin terminal, but got the same result.

---

### Docker Compose file

```
version: "2"

services:
  frontend:
    command: "yarn start"
    image: company/application/frontend:1
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    environment:
      <env entries>
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/opt/app

  backend:
    restart: "no"
    # source ~/.bashrc is needed to add the ssh private key, used by git
    command: bash -c "source ~/.bashrc && yarn run dev"
    image: company/application/backend:1
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    environment:
      <env entries>
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/opt/app
      - ./:/opt:rw
      - ./.ssh/company_utils:/tmp/company_utils
    depends_on:
      - db

  generator-backend:
    restart: "no"
    # source ~/.bashrc is needed to add the ssh private key, used by git
    command: bash -c "source ~/.bashrc && npm run dev"
    image: company/generator/backend:1
    build:
      context: generator-backend
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    environment:
      <env entries>
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./generator-backend:/opt/app
      - ./:/opt:rw
      - ./.ssh/company_utils:/tmp/company_utils
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mongo:3.4
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

volumes:
  mongo:
```

Comment: Can you also paste the content of the docker-file.yml file please?

Comment: @Neekoy, File attached.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turned out it was a matter of file line endings, caused by `git clone`, as pointed out by @mklement0 in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29045187/3127111) to [env: bash\r: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29045140/3127111) question.

Disabling `core.autocrlf` then recloning the repo solved it.

Comment: You just saved my day ! Was not able to find out where the problem is. Thank you very much !