# How to build android project on MacOS from terminal?

Tags: android, macos, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I want to build project in Android Studio 3.1.3 on MacOS High Sierra 10.13 from terminal with command:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

output: bash:\r: No such file or directory.

or

```
/gradlew clean build
```

bash:No such file or directory.

or

```
gradlew clean build
```

bash: gradlew command not found.

How can I execute build from command line ? I have looked on stackoverflow answers, but they didn't help me. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please post the screenshot of your project directory

Comment: @UmarAta added photos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is incorrectly cloned and converted project - see here:
[env: bash\r: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045140/env-bash-r-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: `ls -lah` - this will list all the files in the current directory, you can also type `pwd` to check what directory you're in

Comment: pwd returned: /Users/myUserName/Documents/myProjectFolderName

Comment: so do you have the `gradlew` file? what does `ls -lah` return?

Comment: ls -lah returned: (.gradle, .git, .gitignore, .build.gradle, buildsystem, gradlew, gradle, gradle.properties, .idea, gradlew.bat, settings.gradle, local.properties, data, domain, presentation)

Comment: does it have something like this: `-rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: try `sudo ./gradlew clean install`

Comment: sudo ./gradlew clean install asked me for password and after that wrote that: No such file or directory

Comment: This is super weird as the file exist in the directory you're in, it is executable and it seems that you have the permission to execute it. You might be missing some lib. Try reading this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists. Do you have Android Studio installed OR android SDK?

Comment: I have added photos

Comment: Yes, Android studio and SDK installed. The project is successfully builded from Android studio UI buttons. But it don't want to build from command line.

Comment: This is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045140/env-bash-r-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I was working on Windows and my college on Ubuntu. We both use the same git. But he does not have such problems with command line as I have on Mac.

Comment: What do you mean you use the same git? When you clone a project you can "tell" git to convert all windows-like line endings to UNIX-like. Generally it's a good practice to keep them Unix-like on git repository, and (if you work on Windows) convert them to Windows, then when you commit/push your changes convert them back to UNIX. So it all depends on how you colleague configured his git client. Has the solution I gave you worked for you?

Comment: Can you please help me to modify this command from that link you gave me? sed $'s/\r$//' ./install.sh > ./install.Unix.sh, because I wrote like this, and it's not working: sed $'s/\r$//' ./gradlew > ./gradlew.Unix

Comment: I think you're missing `sh` -> `sed $'s/\r$//' ./gradlew.sh > ./gradlew.Unix.sh`  but this solution isn't pretty. Try setting up proper line endings and cloning the repo again. I think you need to call `git config --global core.autocrlf true` and the clone the repo again. If that doesn't work try with `false` ;/ This will create a new file. check with `ls- lah` if this new file has `-rwxr-xr-x` those x-es mean you can execute this file.

Comment: I will try to do this with my git, because this command also failed. And I have tried and created new sample android project and tried to run gradlew command - and it works there good: ./gradlew clean build. So it's the issue in myProject structure of files...

Comment: If you're on Mac install Sourcetree and clone the repo with Sourcetree. This should be much cleaner. It should ask about the line endings while cloning. Good luck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20510011)

Comment: Unfortunately this answer about missing gradlew is absolutely wrong and probably misleading for the author. Since the author mentioned that `./gradlew clean build` had a bash error logging, this means that the gradlew is already there and its executable (otherwise what would have started bash?). Just open the gradlew file with some text editor (or even Android Studio) and you will see that gradlew is just a bash script.

@SRack this answers the answer of the author pretty good. Since the actual issue is wrongly imported project with some windows characters. Proper import would fix it.

Comment: I changed git config --global core.autocrlf true -- and downloaded project again from git and now it works good.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you have imported the project from a Windows machine and now it contains some carriage returns '\r'.

try to remove carriage returns by executing following commands in your terminal:

```
brew install dos2unix # Installs dos2unix Mac
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \; # recursively removes windows related stuff
```

after that you can use gradle wrapper as usual:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

Comment: Yes, I moved this project from Windows machine. And yes, your script deleted some files (a lot of files). But still, after execution of your script - I have the same issue on executing ./gradlew clean build (and other variants as well).

Comment: it should not have deleted files, but only the carriage characters generated by windows toolchain. which files got removed?

Comment: you could also try to reinstall gradle wrapper (gradlew) by executing following code: `gradle wrapper` if you dont have gradle installed on your macos you can install it by `brew install gradle`

Comment: I spent two days trying to figure this out. Thank you so very much.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I did not import the project from Windows. I just started a new project in Android studio with Kotlin?!

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot. Took about 40 mins. And I see some changes in VCS, but if I look inside, it doesn't show which lines, just some changes;