# After installing npm on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 I get the message "/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I see the following message when running the `npm install` or `npm` command from the terminal. Executing `node` works as expected.

```
    > npm install
    /usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

**Update July 2023:** Microsoft has a [guide for installing Node on WSL using NVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl#install-nvm-nodejs-and-npm). You likely won't have this issue if you follow their how to.

**The fix that has worked for many:** it may be a line endings issue causing problems, but not from Ubuntu. Make sure you have `node` and `npm` installed correctly:

1. From WSL run `sudo apt install nodejs npm` to install node & npm
2. From PowerShell/CMD run `wsl --shutdown` to restart the WSL service
3. From WSL run `which npm` to confirm it's installed (*output should be: /usr/bin/npm*)

Does the problem persist? Try this next:

Stop Windows path variables being shared with WSL by editing the `/etc/wsl.conf` file in WSL. If the file doesn't exist, execute `sudo touch /etc/wsl.conf` first. Edit the file with the command `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf` and add the following configuration:

```ini
[interop]
appendWindowsPath = false
```

Then restart WSL2 with command `wsl --shutdown` in Windows.

***Note 1:*** *This will stop the PATH environment variables from Windows passing through to WSL. Known bug: this stops the VSCode `code .` command from working in WSL. If this is a problem, use NVM solution described here or switch to using node in a docker container.*

***Note 2:*** *this also affects `pyenv` command, see [/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory: Incompatible line-endings (WSL?)](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1725#issuecomment-824054644)*

***Tip from @mike:*** "I did not want to disable the ability to do `code .` so I just removed the windows nodejs path by adding this line to my ~/.bashrc PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's%:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs%%')"

Comment: That worked, but could this potentially cause some other issues down the line?

Comment: @shadoweb it will stop the Windows path being appended to the WSL path. Where you rely on a Windows path being available in WSL, this will no longer be available. I can't think of any instances where this will cause a problem, maybe the Stack overflow community can help?

Comment: OK so it does cause an issue with the shortcut command `code .` but it seems that deactivating the above doesn't break the `npm install` anymore, so I'll leave it like that.

Comment: I had this issue but installed nvm and set it up and didn't have to do this work around.
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: Thanks @zymotik for explaining the problem I was wondering how my WSL got all those windows directories.  I just ran into the same issue after installing a newer version of  of nodejs . I did not want to disable the ability to do code .  so I just removed the windows nodejs path by adding this line to my ~/.bashrc  PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's%:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs%%')

Comment: in case service not starting again use `Get-Service vmcompute | Restart-Service`

Comment: Unsharing the `PATH`variable has helped

Answer (score 13):

I hit the same issue, after install nodejs and npm, just restart my wsl with `wsl --shutdown` solved the issue, you can try this.

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact issue as well, running on same distro & version. After reading everyone's comments, I figured the easiest solution to try first was to 'turn it off and on again' and it worked! I ran this in a windows (not ubuntu) terminal.

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Answer (score 4):

Nodejs has been installed outside the WSL, so I typed the NPM command in the WSL window and actually called the NPM on Windows. After uninstalling both Windows and WSL nodes, I reinstalled the NODE in WSL and there is no problem

Comment: This helps me, `which npm` inside WSL shown that it tried to run the npm version from the `/mnt/c/`

Answer (score 3):

I think the better solution would be installing Node using `nvm` on WSL, then you won't have this problem.

[Installing Nodejs and npm using nvm for Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04/#installing-nodejs-and-npm-using-nvm)

Comment: ...or if you are used to using **Docker**, you could run your commands inside a container using a pattern such as [the three musketeers](https://3musketeers.io/). This will give you _**consistency**_ across platforms, _**control**_ of versions and _**confidence**_ it will work the same in dev as in your pipelines.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the underlying problem is that you installed node using the Nodejs Windows Installer online. The easiest solution to this problem when working with Windows subsystem for Linux is to perform the initial Nodejs install **not** using the Nodejs Windows Installer, but **rather** the following process on your WSL command line:

*Open a new WSL Terminal*

*To enable the download of content from the internet via Ubuntu*:

> $ sudo apt-get install curl

*Then to install nvm (Note: check the latest version of nvm and substitute into the path accordingly; as of this post v0.39.1 is the latest):*

> $ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

*To verify the installation of nvm (Note: you may need to close and reopen your terminal - should return "nvm"):*

> $ command -v nvm

*Install the current stable release of Node.js:*

> $ nvm install --lts

*To confirm you now have node and npm installed:*

> $ node --version && npm --version

And you should see something like:

> v16.16.0

> 8.11.0

It may be beneficial to uninstall your current Nodejs installation and reinstall using the method above. This will save a lot of headaches trying to understand other potential work arounds. Note: the above solution only applies to WSL. Further details can be [found here on the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl).

Comment: I had `nvm` getting rid of it was a journey, but thanks to https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/298 for doing `rm -rf ~/.nvm`

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me today after I updated node and npm through nvm. I realized that indeed the .nvm path was missing from `echo $PATH`. Then I noticed that `npm use v16.14.0` would re-add it to $PATH and make `npm i` work again. However, this only worked for the current tab and to make it work in new sessions/tabs I had to run:

`nvm alias default v16.14.0`

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that uses NVM, a version manager for the node framework. Suggested solution:

Install curl in WSL for downloading from the internet:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Next get the NVM downloader script and run it with bash:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Next, install the long term support version of NVM:

```
nvm install --lts
```

Finally, install node:

```
nvm install node
```

You can find more information about NVM in the [WSL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `npm` has been installed in the wrong place (e.g., in Windows rather than Ubuntu). To check, try running `which npm`.

I had a similar problem which I fixed by restarting my shell after running

`$ sudo apt install npm`.

Now, when I run

`$ which npm`

gives:

`/usr/bin/npm`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, ***sudo*** did the trick. The issue is not fixed, but at least for now, I can move on.

Before:

```
 npm init -y
```

After:

```
sudo npm init -y
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try either of these:

`source ~/.profile`
or
`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Is there any additional info about what your answer has to offer except just trying two commands?

Comment: @treckstar When you install npm, the npm path will be added to .bashrc. And when you close and open the wsl terminal again, the .bashrc file wont run. So you use the command to run the file.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work me. I found it was simply that I had some .js files that had Windows line endings instead of Linux.

The easiest way to fix this was `rm -rf node_modules && npm update` in my project folder to get Linux versions.

Answer (score 0):

You might have other version of node in your windows machine.

`brew link node@<Your Version>` or `brew link node`