# docker env: bash\r: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, bash, docker, pycharm

While locally deploying an app in PyCharm on windows10, I have encountered several mistakes.
Make test command returned following mistake:

```
service "core" is not running container #1 
make: *** [Makefile:60: test] Error 1
```

And indeed container status with the command make ps returned exited(127). When I have checked docker logs for the container in question, I've seen:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
```

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045140/env-bash-r-no-such-file-or-directory), this mistake is connected to how windows processes line endings of files from different OS. The usual solution is:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

But after running the code and  updating current git repo and restarting the containers, i still get the same mistake. What might be the issue here?

Comment: The file still has DOS line endings.  How are you building the image; do you need to re-run `docker build`?  Or, if you're replacing the code in the image with a bind mount, does the file on the host system have the right line endings?

Comment: Check `dos2unix`.

Comment: Hey, David,  I use make and makefile to build the images inside the docker compose. How i can change the DOS endings? The project was downloaded from gitlab and written on macOS or Linux. Inside docker-compose  it should run on ubuntu slice. When is the moment the DOS endings are created?

Comment: and how i can figure out which files are affected?

Comment: I have edited the project code style to run as it's suggested in the link to have Unix and MacOS line separator, but it still returns the same mistake -  Error 1 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What did helped me
I assume that the problem was in the windows line endings in the Unix-based containers.
To solve it I found two very helpful instructions:

1. Configure your line separators in the PyCharm https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html
2. To clarify that changes were really enabled, I have checked the files in the notepad++
   https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v8.1.9.3/
3. Also it was helpful to check the original code because part of the problem was the incorrect spelling of some commands.

Answer (score 8):

When I use Windows in Docker and run a bash script, I have a similar problem, which I solve by using LF instead of CRLDF as the line separator.

in vscode, we can change it here
[image]

Comment: also works for IntelliJ